# I can't create a class based on actual HTML element

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm trying to create a simple gallery with prototype.js and script.aculo.us. To handle left and right arrow I made this code, but it doesn't work

```
Gallery.Arrow = Class.create(document.createElement('a'), {
  initialize: function(listener) {
    this.on('click', listener);
    this.addClassName('xjsl-arrow');
  }
});
```

*this.on* is undefined. I tryed *Class.create($(document.createElement('a')), ...*, or even *Element.extend(this)* in the *initialize* function, but nothing works.

If I tryed *Event.Handler(this, 'click', listener)* to, but the error come from *element.attachEvent* inside prototype.js library.

Is it possible to create a class based on HTML element ?

Answer (score 0):

Try building the Class based on the Element.Methods namespace like this

```
Gallery.Arrow = Class.create(Element.Methods, {
    initialize: function(element,listener) {
        this.on(element,'click', listener);
        this.addClassName(element,'xjsl-arrow');
    }
});
```

jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/rPLa8/

Comment: The problem is the newly created element is not the HTML element itself. What I'm looking for is to create a class which is a subclass of HTMLElement. But thank you for jsfiddle, it could be very usefull.